# Magento 2: Not transferring Item Name to paypal

Tags: magento2, paypal, sku, title

is there a way for the **PayPal express checkout** module to not transmit the **Item title/name** to PayPal?

Example:

**Current Status:**
Item name transmitted to pp: Leggings 3/4 legs whatever blah blah Size L

> Expectation:
>       Item name transmitted to pp: Brand + SKU (or any static name like website name would be cool too)

Any Help would be much appreciated.

D.C.